# Send a message to every AMQP client, except me

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I use RabbitMQ as following :

- Create a direct exchange "FooExchange"
- Connect a client "A" to "FooExchange" with a queue named "client_A_queue"
- Connect a client "B" to "FooExchange" with a queue named "client_B_queue"
- Connect a client "C" to "FooExchange" with a queue named "client_C_queue"

Now, when client "A" publish a message to the exchange, everyone receive it.

Is there anyway to avoid client "A" to receive its own messages ?
(and the same for every client : a client should not receive its own messages)

For the moment I have added a "sender" header with a sender UniqueID and I filter these messages in the client source code, but I think that a better solution should exist.

(in real world situation, I can have many clients, not all clients knows the existence of all other clients)

Thanks.

## EDIT :

Maybe direct exchange is not the good solution. Is there any way to fit my needs only with exchange/queue/routing configuration or should I use code in client applications to filter these messages ?

Of course, if I have 1000 clients connected, I can't really use one routing key for each client and send message to 999 routing keys jsut to exclude one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that this can't be done in RabbitMQ, directly.

There are no negations in routing key matches, so you can't say "all, but not this one" with routing keys or bindings.

> For the moment I have added a "sender" header with a sender UniqueID and I filter these messages in the client source code, but I think that a better solution should exist.

this is pretty much what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

From your comment

> Every client publish messages the same way : to "FooExchange"
>   exchange, with routing key "FooKey". Every client bind it's queue to
>   "FooKey" on "FooExchange

You are not doing the publishing in the correct way. You must define to which exchange and which routing key.So each subscriber with different routing key, since this is what you want. Check [the first tutorial on rabbitmq website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html). Also bare in mind that when using direct exchange, the name of the queue on the subscribing side is the same as the routing key on the publishing side.

Here is how direct exchange works
[image]

taken from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

**EDIT** to answer the edit in the question

 I didn't really understand this part

> I can't really use one routing key for each client and send message to
>   999 routing keys jsut to exclude one.

You would need to specify more precisely what you need.
Anyhow, I suggest that you check out all the types of exchanges:direct, fanout, topic and headers. More info is already in the link I have provided, under the picture.

**EDIT2:**
I think I finally understood what is the use case.
If there is no other criteria which you could use to mark the messages or clients, then you'd have to use fanout exchange, and simply don't react on the message if it's "self-sent". Potentially you could use the headers exchange and use some kind of mappings, but it seems that it would end up on the same. AFAIK, there is not pattern for topic exchange that would include **NOT** *something*.

Comment: Every client publish messages the same way : to "FooExchange" exchange, with routing key "FooKey". Every client bind it's queue to "FooKey" on "FooExchange"

Comment: So every client will receive every message, since they all use the *same routing key* and the same exchange. Do you understand what I wrote for direct exchange in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I understand this tutorial. I have edited my question

Comment: To be clear : I have 1000 clients. When a client send a message, I want the 999 others to receive the message. I don't want the sender to receive its own message. I want this behaviour for all messages sent by all clients.

Comment: Did you read my original question ? I have already added a header and code in clients to avoid self-sent messages. I'm looking for a better/smarter way to do that. (if there is any)

Comment: I did, but the difference is that you said you use direct routing, and in my answer I said to either use fanout or header routing

Comment: Does that make any difference ? I've tried fanout/header and I've got excatly the same behavior